# Where is Blackbeard's Port?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

I Sid Meier's Pirates you can defeat the top 10 pirates of the day. I have killed all of them except Blackbeard. I looked up to find that the pirates usually go to only one port. So the question is where is that port so I can find and Kill Blackbeard?

Comment: That one port is random in any given game, so you will have to ask around in the game to find that out. There is no one single port across all instances of the game as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location of blackbeard's port is always randomized per game.  You have to ask around in taverns (talk to the Barmaids) to get a clue as to where it is.