# Do Major Pirates attack each other?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

In Sid Meier's Pirates can 2 major pirates fight each other? If they did do they now carry the other pirate's golds with them? The Reason I'm asking is because Instead of finding all ten maybe I could defeat a "super pirate". Is this possible?

Comment: [Didn't you already kill the other nine](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127481/where-is-blackbeards-port), making this impossible even if the game does work that way?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, but the question isn't just for Young Guilo; it's for him, and for everyone else in the community with the same question. Besides, he may have started a new game or likewise.

Comment: @avestar101 Yeah, but when an asker gives a reason, we do expect it to not be made up. Making up reasons to ask questions is heavily frowned on because it strongly correlates with low quality. Considering the votes, this isn't an exception.

Comment: @Seven Unless he asks and answers his own question in one swoop, which is encouraged

Comment: We really shouldn't be in the business of guessing at the questioner's motives. They don't matter. [A question should stand on its own and be upvoted or downvoted as such.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7241/3062) Bringing the user into it and semi-attacking them in comments is not productive. That said, [I do feel this question is just wild speculation](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3198/3062) and I left a downvote for that reason.

Comment: @All I merely asked the question out of curiosity. I had played other games before and was tired of defeating all ten and wondered if there was such thing as a short cut.

Comment: @Sterno There is a pattern of this user asking whatever random guess pops into their head. It's not strictly against any site rules, but it's definitely an abuse of the spirit of the site. This user's question history indicates that future questions *shouldn't* have the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: So down vote or close vote where appropriate. I don't see how attacking the user in comments will produce any positive effect.

Comment: @Sterno It's a no win scenario. When he gets downvoted anonymously, it ends up on Meta. When he gets down votes with comments explaining [*why it's being downvoted*](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3198/3062), there's a backlash in said comments. A stupid thought experiment is a stupid thought experiment, and it is not a useful question. It deserves downvotes, sometimes closure, and if someone is bold enough to do so without fear of reprisal, and is willing to articulate the specific issues, *it deserves to be called out as stupid*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I killed blackbeard after three pirates and, really, the end game is blackbeard. From my experience there was no super pirate but killing the lowers after a specific raid event will generate more gold than randomly attacking.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the specific raid events?

Comment: The game will alert you to something along the lines of "A famous pirate is leaving the port-au-prince." Or from talking to the maiden at the tavern you will get something like "A famous pirate was last seen near the port-au-prince he's carrying 500 doublons." Occasionally upon arrival of the port you might see another pirate with the famous pirate, or the pirate in question leaving the port. If it is his rival port, he will have conducted a "raid" where he is carrying more amounts of gold than the standard "500 doublons." This is completely random and occurs rarely.